# Reading replies in Pushbullet using python

Tags: python, pushbullet

Can we read PushBullet's user's reply and continue the program further on the basis of that reply using Python?

```py
from pushbullet import * 
pb =PushBullet(<API>)
pb.push_note('Hi',"Shall I continue?")        #notification sent
```

If I write "Yes" as reply to that message, it should comprehend my reply and continue the program further.